# Building jQuery DOM elements from a module

Tags: javascript, jquery, dom

I really like to modularize my code into separate files, usually because I am writing something that should be able to take some parameters and then easily end up attaching to a DOM element on anyone's page. These modules are usually graphical representations of something like a network topology, and this requires a lot of divs and a decent amount of parameters.

My question is when building up the DOM structure, (and when NOT talking about 100s of rows for tables, as an example) what is the best method? These are my own routes and I still struggle to determine which one is best.

**As String Pieces**

---

```
var myModule1 = function (options) {
    this.userContainer = options.container;
    this.wrapper = '<div class = "mm1-wrapper"/>';
    this.piece1 = '<div class = "mm1-piece1"/>';
    this.piece2 = '<div class = "mm1-piece2"/>';
    this.piece3 = '<div class = "mm1-piece3"/>';
}

myModule1.prototype.build = function () {
    var wrap = $(this.wrapper).append(this.piece, this.piece2, this.piece3, );
    this.userContainer.append(wrap);
}
```

**As jQuery pieces in a collection**

---

```
var myModule2 = function (options) {
    this.userContainer = options.container;
    this.wrapper = $('<div class = "mm1-wrapper"/>');
    this.peices = {
        1: $('<div class = "mm1-piece1"/>'),
        2: $('<div class = "mm1-piece2"/>'),
        3: $('<div class = "mm1-piece3"/>')
    }
}
//Using an each loop to append
myModule2.prototype.build = function () {
    $.each(this.piece, function (i, e) {
        this.wrapper.append(e);
    });
    this.userContainer.append(this.wrapper);
}
```

I'm just looking for some insight about

1) Is it resource heavy to store things as jQuery objects?

2) Is it resource heavy to store large pieces in a collection?

3) This is how I have been creating my modules, but I am obviously insecure about them. Does any of this structure make sense?

Comment: Do you know what a "module" is? As commonly used, it's not a synonym for "function" or even for "constructor".

Comment: A module is an independent entity that can be used to construct more complex systems. Just because there is a "community term" for it doesn't mean I cannot use the English definition for it.

Comment: For sure, you're free, within reason, to express yourself however you want, but you will communicate better if you adopt standard meanings for standard terms. "Module" is generally used to mean a singleton namespace - not a class or constructor. See **[here](http://yuiblog.com/blog/2007/06/12/module-pattern/)**, for example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To answer your questions:

1- Not really

2- Not really

3- If it works for you and you've already got something working, then don't sweat it.

Of course, I would strongly recommend you look into a framework like [Angular](https://angularjs.org/) or [React](http://facebook.github.io/react/)

You can split your logic from your html templates in different files. Imo, it's wayyyy cleaner and wayyyy easier to debug an html file than a list of strings in a javascript file. The learning curve is harsh, but well worth it.

Check [ng-Repeat](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngRepeat) for angular.

Cheers!